# Tableau dual axis map exclude zero value bubbles

Tags: filter, maps, tableau-api, bubble-chart

I am working with a dual axis map in Tableau and I am displaying one measure as color density on the map and another measure as bubbles on the same map.

The 2nd measure has null values - but the null values display as very little dots in the map. Is there any way to exclude them?

I tried to filter the 2nd measure to exclude null values, but then the first measure is filtered the same way.

[image: Tableau example]

Comment: You can try making a new calculated measure of:
`IF [YOUR MEASURE] = >0 THEN [YOUR DIMENSION] END`
This won't contain any values less than 0, if you use this in place of your current field it should remove the small blobs.

Comment: Another option for this, create a measure using ISNULL:
`IF ISNULL([YOUR MEASURE]) THEN "Nulls" ELSE "Not Null" END`
Then drag this onto the filters shelf to exclude the nulls from this dimension only.

Comment: I tried the first option and it works the same way as the filter, it does make the little bubbles dissapear, but also the colors for those counties

Comment: Post a subset of your data